# Codeigniter use function in a function in a helperfunction

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to use a function inside another function in a helper of codeigniter.

So normaly i can do it with this

```
 function first($val){
    $ci= & get_instance();

   //do something
    return "hello";
}

function second($val){
      $ci= & get_instance();
    $this->first($val);

// try to do this failed also
// $ci->first($val);

}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: unless you've placed your function inside class struct, '$this' wouldn't work.

Comment: it seem that it work if i call the function directly without $ci and without $this

Comment: I suspect you've not placed it inside class, that is why you're able to call function with without class

Comment: Can you paste the mock code you're using for your hook

Comment: `$this` referes to the current class that you are referencing. Are you using it inside of the object? From the little info you gave us, it doesnt seem to be that way, that is why when you remove `this` it will work since you are using a function that is loaded into memory. Please provide more information. or read this https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the first function in another function like that.

```
 function first($val){
    $ci= & get_instance();

   //do something
    return "hello";
}

function second($val){
    $ci= & get_instance();
    first($val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unlike most other systems in CodeIgniter, Helpers are not written in an Object Oriented format. They are simple, procedural functions. Each helper function performs one specific task, with no dependence on other functions. ([Reference](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html#helper-functions))

So, You should use without `$this`

```
function second($val){
    $ci= & get_instance();
    first($val);
}
```

However, If you define those function inside a class (In a controller, model etc.). You should use `$this`.

```
class Control extends CI_Controller{
    function first($val){
         $ci= & get_instance();

        //do something
        return "hello";
    }

   function second($val){
       $ci= & get_instance();
       $this->first($val);
    }
}
```